# Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'User[]'

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

I can not understand this error ,
why it won't allow me to post data to users array so i can access it from the html ?

this is the component

```
export class Service1Component implements OnInit {

  selectedUser: User;
  users: Array<User>;

 constructor(private _userService: UserService) { }

 ngOnInit() {
   this._userService.getUsers()
   .subscribe(resUserData => {
     this.users = resUserData
   });
 }

 onSelectUser(user:any){
   this.selectedUser = user;
 }
}
```

this is the service i want to subscribe to

```
export class UserService {

 private _getUrl = '/api/users'

 constructor(private _http: Http) { }

 getUsers(){
   return this._http.get(this._getUrl)
   .map((response: Response) => {
     response.json();
   })
 }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Paste your code instead of a screen shot. And also please add userService code.

Comment: Please post real code, and not an image. Also post the getUsers method. Seems like you are missing a return there

Comment: okay one moment

Comment: okay done ,, Can you now please help

Comment: You need to either `return response.json();` or remove the surrounding `{}`s and `;`. As a side note, consider using `HttpClient` instead of the now-deprecated `Http`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed to return from your function which is considered as `void` in your component.

```
getUsers(){
   return this._http.get(this._getUrl)
   .map((response: Response) => {
    return response.json();   // add return statement
   })
}
```

Comment: Facepalm. How did I miss this?

Answer (score 2):

Just initialize your users

```
users : User[] = [];
```

**EDIT**

After editing your question, i see you have missed to return the response in your service

```
 return this._http.get(this._getUrl)
   .map((response: Response) => {
     return response.json();
 })
```

Comment: To those who downvoted without reason, the initial question did not have the code just the image of the component. hope you understand and revoke the downvote of mine and pixelbits

Answer (score 2):

Your get answers method is not returning anything, because your map function doesn't return. You don't even need the map function, because the 'new' `HttpClient` does this automatically. Try this

```
getUsers() { 
  return this._http.get(this._getUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If arrow function return single value you don't need to use `return` statement

```
getUsers(){
   return this._http.get(this._getUrl)
   .map((response: Response) => response.json())
 }
```

> If you use HttpClient you don't need to `.map((response: Response) => response.json())` it's automatically calls response.json() internally.

Answer (score -3):

You should scope the subscribe in a block:

```
.subscribe(resUserData => {
    this.users = resUserData;
});
```